# NetBeans automatically restores files edited from another application

Tags: java, netbeans

NetBeans keeps restoring files I edited on Notepad++ the way they were before they were edited. How do I stop this?

Comment: Stop editing files in two places at the same time? Stop editing files marked autogenerated (which at the top say they should not be edited)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option **Enable auto-scanning of sources** which is enabled by default. You can switch off this option to prevent this behavior. 
The option can be found in

> Options dialog ---> Miscellaneous category ---> Files tab.

To manually scan for changes do the following:

> source ---> scan for external changes